# using NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithData in swift

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

Trying to use the code block below, but don't know how to get the options bit to work in the else clause, I keep getting 'NSPropertyListMutabilityOptions' is not convertible to 'NSPropertyListReadOptions'. But the Read options don't have MutableContainersWithLeaves that I need.

```
//if the file does not already exist
    if(appStatsData != nil) {
        appStats.setObject(NSNumber.numberWithInt(0), forKey:"RunCount")
        appStats.setObject("No Courses Viewed", forKey:"LastCourseViewed")
    }else {
        appStats = NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithData(appStatsData, options:     NSPropertyListMutabilityOptions.MutableContainersAndLeaves, format: nil, error: &error)
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `options` parameter has the type `NSPropertyListReadOptions` which is a type alias
for `Int`.

`NSPropertyListMutabilityOptions` is a `RawOptionSetType` with `Uint` as the underlying
raw type.

Therefore you have to convert the option to an `Int` with

```
appStats = NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithData(appStatsData,
    options:Int(NSPropertyListMutabilityOptions.MutableContainersAndLeaves.rawValue),
    format: nil, error: &error)
```

Comment: I think you need to use `rawValue` instead of `toRaw()`.

Comment: @DylanBettermann: You are completely right, that changed between Xcode 6.0 and 6.1.